# Calculating standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I need to do a algorithm to calculate an integral via Monte Carlo Method, and for a purpose of simulation, I need to calculate the standard deviation of a sample generated in my program.
My problem is that, when I am increasing the number of elements of my sample, my standard deviation does not decay, as I should expect. 
First I thought that my function was wrong, but using the numpy pre defined function to calculate the standard deviation, I saw that the values were the same and it was not decreasing as I expected. So I wondered that what was wrong was my sample, so I made the following simulation to test if the standard deviation was decreasing as it should do:

```
list = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100)]
print np.std(list)
```

the standard deviation obtained: 0.289

```
list = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(1000)]
print np.std(list)
```

the standard deviation obtained: 0.287

Shouldn't this decrease while my n increases? Because I need this to use as stopping criterion in my simulation, and I was excepcting this to decreases with a bigger sample. What is wrong with my mathematical concept?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable, it is used to make a list.

Comment: what should I use, then? Array?

Comment: Umm... it _does_ decrease in your example. `0.289 > 0.287`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My friend, I just calculated 2 values. If I do it more times, some values are even bigger for greater n

Comment: `random.uniform` is a stochastic process. So it is very likely that some instances of larger lists have a higher standard deviation than some instances of smaller lists. The probability of this happening should be low, though - which is what you're after.

Comment: Use a list, but don't make the variable of the list `list`, call it something like `list_of_nums`, pretty much anything other than function names.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, all such lists (regardless of size) will have the same standard deviation with an error given by the standard error, and an equal (not low) probability of being higher or lower than the actual population standard devation, which is `1/sqrt(12)`.  See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard deviation of a distribution does not depend on the sample size.  The [standard deviation for a uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) is `(b - a)/sqrt(12)` where `a` and `b` are the limits of your distribution.  In your case, `a = 0` and `b = 1`, so you should expect `std = 1/sqrt(12) = 0.288675` for any size sample.

Perhaps what you're looking for is the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error), which is given by `std/sqrt(N)` and will decrease as your sample size increases:

```
In [9]: sample = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)

In [10]: sample.std()/np.sqrt(sample.size)
Out[10]: 0.029738347511343809

In [11]: sample = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)

In [12]: sample.std()/np.sqrt(sample.size)
Out[12]: 0.0091589707054713591
```

Answer (score 4):

No, your mathematical concept is not flawed, standard deviation remains constant for larger n.
What AHuman correctly points out is that you should avoid using reserved keywords for your variable names: list is a python reserved keyword. Use my_list or some other variable name instead.

[edit] Because the calculated mean is random, error bounds will not work; you will have to calculate the confidence interval which in this case is a probabilistic error bound. You can look here for more info: http://planetmath.org/montecarlosimulation

Comment: Ok, so I was thinking to use the ratio between standard deviation and sample mean to stop my simulation. This defines an relative error, which is given, and I was thinking to use it to get the best n and the best estimation for my integral. How this can be a good criteria, since the standard deviation will remain constant?

Comment: I've already changed the name of my list, thanks.